# Which digital modes are formally specified sufficiently to be implemented?

Tags: digital-modes, dsp

Which currently popular digital/SDR modes do not require a pre-compiled library or pre-written source code?  (e.g. has actually been used for QSOs as implemented from specification or sufficiently complete description by other than the original developer?)

(For purposes of this question, C source code is not considered a specification, unless the comments alone allow re-implementation in another programming language.  Automatic translation of FORTRAN to C is not considered a specification.  The possibility of reverse engineering some software library is also not considered a specification of the digital mode.  Assuming an non-existent spec could potentially be written is not considered a specification (unless you can and have written it!).

Comment: Are you asking which currently popular digital modes have more than one existing software implementation, or which such modes have sufficient specifications to allow new implementations?  I can imagine that there might be sufficiently-specified modes that currently only have a single software implementation.

Comment: One might even question whether a digital mode with a single software implementation, and no public spec is even legal to use in amateur bands.  It could be interpreted as an encryption with the undocumented software blob as the public key.

Comment: A specification written by a sole implementer may or may not be a sufficient and complete spec. There is a reason why industry consortiums (BLE SIG, et.al.) have compatibility testing labs/sessions.)

Comment: @hotpaw2 as I read the question and your comments here, would it be appropriate to change the question title to "Which digital modes are formally specified sufficiently for re-implementation?"

Comment: @hotpaw2 D-STAR and DMR use a proprietary AMBE codec, and these modes are commonly used in the US. So it seems at least in the US, that question has been answered.

Comment: Also, why would publicly available source code _not_ count as a specification? It's precise, accurate, and available: everything one could want in a spec.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II I kind of beg to differ... my Fortran-fu is really not up to par to K1JT's mad Fortran skills, and WSJT is the source of all truth for a few standards, which at least partially annoys me.

Comment: @W8II : Requiring reverse engineering of code (for instance to reimplement in another programming language) is NOT the same as a specification, IMO.  (Unless the code comments alone are complete). That’s just a statement of the Turing completeness of the programming languages.  And a spec is different than a theoretical CS proof of (im)possibility.

Comment: especially, when you reverse engineer a transmitter, you only learn to transmit the same subset of the actual standard. That doesn't allow you to write a receiver for all *possible standards-compliant* transmissions.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II The fact that something is commonly done doesn't make it right or legal.  Witness the number of cars above the speed limit on any highway on any day.  Lack of enforcement doesn't imply acceptance.  I agree with the opinion that a mode that requires proprietary libraries to work may violate the rule against encryption of transmissions, never mind if "anyone" can download and install the software to receive it.  What if I don't have the right OS?

Comment: @ZeissIkon I agree, I'd take even further: for AMBE, you need to pay for a device that the manufacturer paid a license fee for. Meaning that you might have the right OS, but maybe not 100€ and so it's not available to you, negating the mutual self-regulating motivation behind requiring hams to use decodable modes.

Comment: Maybe I not only don’t have the “right” OS, but any CPU at all, such as for a pure gate level or FPGA implemented SDR.  Lots of state machines, FMACs and FFTs, but no C compiler target.

Comment: Reading source code is not usually considered reverse engineering, unless that source code has been deliberate obfuscated. Source code is _designed_ to be read and understood. Granted some people are especially bad at writing clearly, but that goes for English as much as Fortran. Sounds like what you're really asking is "what digital modes are specified in a particularly easy way which I can personally understand", which is not only subjective, but an open-ended list question.

Comment: Source code is a specific implementation, not a document that would (alone) pass muster as a complete ISO or ANSI specification, or other legal document (say, suitable to be FCC compliant).  Working code can be extremely poorly written and unreadable (and still work).

Comment: @hotpaw2 By the same token, written formal specifications can be very difficult to understand, either because they're poorly written or simply because they have to cover every single possibility in order to be correct. Authors often provide reference implementations because the source code is easier to understand than the actual specification.

Comment: Agreed.  A working reference implementation as an appendix to a complete spec would probably be a good option.  But a spec that covers the full range allows interoperable implementations, which often end doing better at the standard than the initial reference imp.

Comment: I believe this is an open ended question that is only answerable by either attempting to implement a specific protocol or by searching the code history of every known implementation of a protocol to see if there is more than one lineage.  I tend to agree with others here that an open or public domain code implementation should satisfy as a specification.  However, if you are just looking for a well documented protocol, psk31 and codec2 might both satisfy.

Comment: random code == FCC communication specification?  That may be wishful thinking... unless you can point at a legal court precedent.

Comment: No, I don't think code implementation is a FCC specification.  But then, FCC specifications rarely give more information than bandwidth and the nature of the data being modulated (phone, data, image, etc.)  Most of the FCC specs I've seen seem to care more about what is being modulated than how.

Comment: For instance, find the FCC specs for ATSC or HD radio.